# can't understand how to call this function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a third party dll added to my web application.one of the function looks like this

```
public InterestCategory[] gvc(string st)
{
    object[] results = this.Invoke("getit", new object[] {
                    st});
    return ((InterestCategory[])(results[0]));
}
```

as you can see the function returns `InterestCategory[]`.When I checked (GoToDefinition) InterestCategory I can see this

```
  public partial class InterestCategory
{
    private string descriptionField;
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return this.descriptionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.descriptionField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And now In my code I am trying to call this function like this

```
  API.InterestCategory IC = new API.InterestCategory();
  IC  =    api.gvc(st);
```

it throws an error like this

```
 Cannot implicitly convert type 'API.InterestCategory[]' to 'API.InterestCategory'
```

Can any one tell me what is the correct procedure to call this function

Comment: Look at the return type `InterestCategory[]` now look at what you are setting the return value to `InterestCategory`. Now look at the error message: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'API.InterestCategory[]' to 'API.InterestCategory'`. It should now be obvious that you need store the return value in a `InterestCategory[]`..

Comment: +1 Because the question was voted down, but being a noob should be frowned upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying the wrong type for the variable. You have told the compiler you want to create a single variable of type `InterestCategory` when the function is returning an array, `InterestCategory[]`.

Change your code to this and it should work fine:

```
API.InterestCategory[] ICs;
ICs = api.gvc(securityToken);
```

Answer (score 2):

`IC` should be an array of `Api.InterestCategory`. Instead, you are declaring the variable as `Api.InterestCategory`. Try:

```
Api.InterestCategory[] IC = api.GetValidInterestsCategories(securityToken);
```

Answer (score 2):

The method returns an array, so you must assign the result to a variable of the correct type:

```
InterestCategory[] ics = api.gvc(securityToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

`API.InterestCategory IC = new API.InterestCategory();`

so typing

`IC = api.gvc` is mistake because IC is `InterestCategory` not `InterestCategory[]`

Try:

```
var IC = api.gvc(securityToken)
```

Answer (score 0):

hello you are doing everything right but the problem you are getting due to mismatch of return type and variable in which you want to store it..i don't know why are you not able to Understand this problem..it belongs to the basics of programming..so do this.

```
api.InterestCategory[] ic = api.gvc(securityToken);
```